# Debugger jumps back in VS2015

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I've just witnessed some strange behavior while debugging in VS2015. When I debug, for some reason the debugger jumps back to a certain point and eventually this causes to throw an exception. Weird thing is that I only get this exception when I debug, I don't get this exception if I just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

My FinalImage: `private System.Windows.Controls.Image FinalImage{ get; set; }`

Why does this happen? It jumps back at `FinalImage.Source` for some reason and I don't understand why. See this gif:

[image]

Exception says that I cannot convert a bitmap to uri... Thanks for help!

Comment: This can be due to multithreading, have you checked if your current thread changes when you "jump back"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible reasons for this behavior:

- The `FinalImage.Source` property setter calls (possibly indirectly) your `ImagePath` setter again. Check the *Call Stack* window if it's the case.
- There's a second thread executing the same code, and it hit your breakpoint while you were setting `FinalImage.Source`. Check the *Threads* window.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/7ff5f8c5d6b50deecf0ae7852fb571fe.gif Look here. What can I do about it?

Comment: @Derp look at the *call stack* window, you're clearly in the first case. I don't know what you can do as I have no clue what your code is *supposed* to do.

Comment: Ah I already think I get it. I'm using twoway binding with an MVVM pattern to select an image with a `FileDialog` and update a current picture. I guess that when I change the source of the FileImage, the bindmode gets triggered or something in a different thread and does something with the setter. I guess that can be the only thing. Sounds legit? I just figured out though that the whole FileImage.Source thing isn't necessary since the twoway binding takes care of that.

Comment: @Derp you're on the UI thread all along, there is no other thread involved. I can't comment further, I don't know your code.

Comment: Well, thanks anyways :-) you helped me find unnecessary code which apparently caused the exception, the exception is gone now and redundant code is gone too, so thank you!